# Create a helper class to read and write to / from a plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

First of all this is not a question on how to read or write to a plist.

I have been reading and writing to the same PList from different parts of my program and I got to the point where I got tired of repeating code over and over and I was thinking to create a reusable class for this type of task but I want to make sure that this is not a crazy idea.

1. What do you use to read and write to the same plist from different parts of your program?
2. Do you see any performance issues by using a helper to read and write to a plist.
3. Does this sound like a crazy idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I personally made one: [HERE](https://github.com/LoganWright/PlistModel)

Basically, you create a subclass with property names matching your keys and it's populated at runtime.

Your Plist:

[image]

And subclass:

```
#import "PlistModel.h"

@interface CustomModel : PlistModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * StringPropertyKey;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * DatePropertyKey;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray * ArrayPropertyKey;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary * DictionaryPropertyKey;

@property int IntPropertyKey;
@property BOOL BoolPropertyKey;
@property float FloatPropertyKey;

@end
```

And access:

```
[CustomModel plistNamed:@"CustomModel" inBackgroundWithBlock:^(PlistModel *plistModel) {

    // Get the plist
    CustomModel * customModel = (CustomModel *)plistModel;

    // Populated properties 
    NSLog(@"PlistIncluded - StringProperty: %@", customModel.StringPropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"PlistIncluded - DateProperty: %@", customModel.DatePropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"PlistIncluded - ArrayProperty: %@", customModel.ArrayPropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"PlistIncluded - DictionaryProperty: %@", customModel.DictionaryPropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"PlistIncluded - IntProperty: %i", customModel.IntPropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"PlistIncluded - BoolProperty: %@", customModel.BoolPropertyKey ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSLog(@"PlistIncluded - FloatProperty: %f", customModel.FloatPropertyKey);

}];
```

It auto saves on dealloc, or you can call save.  If it's not a bundle plist and you're editing it, you can set the properties and they'll automatically sync the Plist.

Comment: Cool, it's fairly new, so let me know if you come across problems I might have missed.  It's been pretty consistent in the project I developed it for :)

Answer (score 1):

1. A pair of helper functions must be enough
2. I don't think so
3. No, it's a good idea

Answer (score 1):

1) You could use a class rather than an object

2) No. But what makes you think there might be?

3) Of course not, again, why do you think it might be?

The fact that you ask 2 in particular, and to a lesser extent 3 implies you might have some wrong assumptions or misconceptions about something. It might be useful to you to describe
 your reasoning behind asking those.

Answer (score 1):

1. I used a data manager with helper functions so the data is
   segregated from the other layers of the application.
2. None.
3. Crazy? No. Needed? Yes.